# How do I extend my ruby class with a c extension?

Tags: c, ruby, inline, ruby-c-extension

If I have Foo::Bar written in Ruby, and I want to add a method to Bar as a C extension.  Right now when I create Foo::Bar in C like this:

```
static VALUE Foo;
static VALUE Bar;

static VALUE 
print_string(VALUE self, VALUE string) {
  printf("%s", StringValuePtr(string));
  return Qnil;
}

void Init_foo() {
    Foo = rb_define_module("Foo");
    Bar = rb_define_class_under(Foo, "Bar", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_method(Bar, "print_string", print_string, 1);
}
```

But the problem is:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'ext/foo'   #=> ["Foo"]
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > f = Foo::Bar.new   #=> #<Foo::Bar:0x000001046bce48>
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > f.original_ruby_method
NoMethodError: undefined method `original_ruby_method' for #<Foo::Bar:0x000001046bce48>
```

So I am essentially overwriting the original Foo::Bar.  How do I extend it and not overwrite it?

Comment: Checkout the gem called 'RubyInline'.  It is used by the gem called 'image_science' which makes calls to c code to manipulate images.

Comment: Yeah I know about RubyInline, but would rather not use it since it doesn't support all data types.  I also am going to be writing alot of C, and it would be nice to keep it all separate.

Comment: I assume you actually have defined Foo::Bar#original_ruby_method somewhere in your Ruby code there - which isn't seen in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to your solution, where you require your Ruby code from your C extension, would be to require the extension from the Ruby code.

Add `require 'foo.so'` or `require 'ext/foo.so'` (depending on where your compiled library ends up) to `lib/foo.rb`, then in the client code just call `require 'foo'` as normal (assuming `lib` is on your load path).

I think doing it this way round is clearer and more common.

Note that you can use the `.so` suffix even if your platform produces something else, i.e. it'll still work on a mac when the actual file is a `.bundle`.

Comment: That does look cleaner, but when I try that I get: "NameError: Bar is already defined"

Comment: @Jeremy I can't reproduce that error - what is the line it's being raised from? Have you got your `require 'foo.so'` at the top or bottom of the rb file?

Comment: @Jeremy this is what I've got, if you want a look: https://gist.github.com/1041242

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to solve this issue.

```
void Init_foo() {
    rb_eval_string("require './lib/foo'");
    VALUE Bar = rb_path2class("Foo::Bar");
    rb_define_method(Bar, "print_string", print_string, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function a bit hidden away - I had to dig into the source to find it, but you can use `rb_const_get` to get references to existing modules and classes.

```
void Init_foo() {
  Foo = rb_const_get( rb_cObject, rb_intern("Foo");
  Bar = rb_const_get( Foo, rb_intern("Bar");
  rb_define_method(Bar, "print_string", print_string, 1);
}
```

If you want to ensure the class/module is created if it doesn't exist:

```
void Init_foo() {
  if ( rb_const_defined( rb_cObject, rb_intern("Foo") ) )
    Foo = rb_const_get( rb_cObject, rb_intern("Foo");
  else
    Foo = rb_define_module("Foo");

  if ( rb_const_defined( Foo, rb_intern("Bar") ) )
    Bar = rb_const_get( Foo, rb_intern("Bar");
  else
    Bar = rb_define_class_under(Foo, "Bar", rb_cObject);

  rb_define_method(Bar, "print_string", print_string, 1);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to build on an existing constant.